# How to reuse create_user code in create_superuser?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-1.7

I have a custom `BaseUserManager` and `AbstractBaseUser`. I want to reuse the `create_user` function in `AbstractBaseUser` for my `superuser` code since the requirements are the same.

From what I understand, I could pass the arguments passed to `create_superuser` right over to `create_user` and then save that locally inside the function, change the `is_admin` to `True` and then return it. That would recycle a lot of code and keep things clean. Is this a proper approach?

```
def create_superuser(self, email, var2, var3, var4, etc...):
    user = create_user(email, var2, var3, var4, etc...)
    user.is_admin = True
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user
```

I'm mostly wondering if calling `user.save(using=self._db)` twice, once in `create_user` and once in `create_superuser` on the same user is safe?

Comment: There is already already a `create_superuser` for you - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_superuser why recreate it ?

Comment: I tried to leave it out of the `BaseUserManager`, but they wanted me to implement it into my customer manager...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a look at how [Django did it](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L166):

```
class MyCustomUserManager(models.Manager):
    def _create_user(self, email, is_staff, is_superuser, ...):
        ...

    def create_user(self, email, ...):
        return self._create_user(email, False, False, ...)

    def create_superuser(self, email, ...):
        return self._create_user(email, True, True, ...)
```

This will minimize both extra code and database access. While there is nothing particularly wrong with saving the user twice, it is utterly unnecessary.

Comment: Checking out their code, and getting an error `TypeError: _create_user() takes exactly 12 arguments (13 given)`. The parameters (`def` line) include self and the arguments (`return` line) do not. I don't understand why I'm getting it then.

Comment: @User Can you post your `Manager`?